# using XSL to convert FMP to WordPress

Tags: xslt

I'm trying to export a product database out of FileMakerPro into a WordPress import XML structure.

There are many fields in the desired XML structure that I don't need to add values to, but there are some fields that I need to update. Once I have a working prototype I should be able to put the finishing touches on it.

I'm using a program called XSLPallete to do the transform. Are there other easy ways to apply the XSL to the XML?

The exported data

```
<RESULTSET FOUND="745">
        <ROW MODID="108" RECORDID="586">
            <COL>
                <DATA>Product 1 name</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>$XXX.XX</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>image reference</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>product description</DATA>
            </COL>
        </ROW>
        <ROW MODID="48" RECORDID="587">
            <COL>
                <DATA>Product two name</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>$XXX.XX<DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>image reference</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>product description</DATA>
            </COL>
        </ROW>
```

Here is the desired output structure

```
<item>
    <title>Product Name</title>
    <link>url + post_name</link>
    <pubDate>date</pubDate>
    <dc:creator>user</dc:creator>
    <guid isPermaLink="false"></guid>
    <description></description>
    <content:encoded><![CDATA[]]></content:encoded>
    <excerpt:encoded><![CDATA[]]></excerpt:encoded>
    <wp:post_id>29</wp:post_id>
    <wp:post_date>timestamp</wp:post_date>
    <wp:post_date_gmt>timestamp</wp:post_date_gmt>
    <wp:comment_status>open</wp:comment_status>
    <wp:ping_status>open</wp:ping_status>
    <wp:post_name>post_name</wp:post_name>
    <wp:status>publish</wp:status>
    <wp:post_parent>0</wp:post_parent>
    <wp:menu_order>0</wp:menu_order>
    <wp:post_type>product</wp:post_type>
    <wp:post_password></wp:post_password>
    <wp:is_sticky>0</wp:is_sticky>
    <category domain="product_cat" nicename="the_category"><![CDATA[Apple]]></category>
    <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key>_edit_last</wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[3]]></wp:meta_value>
    </wp:postmeta>
    <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key>seo_follow</wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[false]]></wp:meta_value>
    </wp:postmeta>
    <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key>seo_noindex</wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[false]]></wp:meta_value>
    </wp:postmeta>
    <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key>total_sales</wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[0]]></wp:meta_value>
    </wp:postmeta>
    <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key>_regular_price</wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[2499]]></wp:meta_value>
    </wp:postmeta>
    <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key>_sale_price</wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[]]></wp:meta_value>
    </wp:postmeta>
    <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key>_tax_status</wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[taxable]]></wp:meta_value>
    </wp:postmeta>
    <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key>_tax_class</wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[]]></wp:meta_value>
    </wp:postmeta>
    <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key>_visibility</wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[visible]]></wp:meta_value>
    </wp:postmeta>
    <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key>_purchase_note</wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[]]></wp:meta_value>
    </wp:postmeta>
    <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key>_featured</wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[yes]]></wp:meta_value>
    </wp:postmeta>
    <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key>_weight</wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[4]]></wp:meta_value>
    </wp:postmeta>
    <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key>_length</wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[45]]></wp:meta_value>
    </wp:postmeta>
    <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key>_width</wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[35]]></wp:meta_value>
    </wp:postmeta>
    <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key>_height</wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[10]]></wp:meta_value>
    </wp:postmeta>
    <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key>_sku</wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[9999]]></wp:meta_value>
    </wp:postmeta>
    <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key>_product_attributes</wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[a:0:{}]]></wp:meta_value>
    </wp:postmeta>
    <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key>_downloadable</wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[no]]></wp:meta_value>
    </wp:postmeta>
    <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key>_virtual</wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[no]]></wp:meta_value>
    </wp:postmeta>
    <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key>_sale_price_dates_from</wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[]]></wp:meta_value>
    </wp:postmeta>
    <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key>_sale_price_dates_to</wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[]]></wp:meta_value>
    </wp:postmeta>
    <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key>_price</wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[$price]]></wp:meta_value>
    </wp:postmeta>
    <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key>_stock</wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[]]></wp:meta_value>
    </wp:postmeta>
    <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key>_stock_status</wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[instock]]></wp:meta_value>
    </wp:postmeta>
    <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key>_backorders</wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[no]]></wp:meta_value>
    </wp:postmeta>
    <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key>_manage_stock</wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[no]]></wp:meta_value>
    </wp:postmeta>
    <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key>_thumbnail_id</wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[30]]></wp:meta_value>
    </wp:postmeta>
</item>
```

Comment: I assume that your "Exported data" is your XSLT input? Please confirm. Please supply your input document and rules of transformation.

Comment: Hi Sean, yes the "exported data" (from FMP) is the XSLT input. The rules are basically 
RESULTSET.ROW[i].COL[0].DATA -> item.title
RESULTSET.ROW[i].COL[1].DATA -> item.wp:postmeta.wp:meta_value into <![CDATA[]]> (where meta_key == _price ) this is the challenge

Comment: This is way not enough information. For example item/link - where does that information come from? Or item/pubdate? or a hundred other fields? Not clear at all.

Comment: Initially some of these values will be hard-coded and others will be left empty. At the moment I'm just trying to get a start so that I can see if this will work or if I need to try a different approach altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an XSLT 1.0 style-sheet to get you started. You can build on this once you have decided the rules of transformation.

This style-sheet, when applied to your sample input ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/> 

<xsl:template match="/">
 <items>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="RESULTSET/ROW" />
  </items>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ROW">
 <item>
   <title><xsl:value-of select="COL[1]/DATA" /></title>
   <description><xsl:value-of select="COL[4]/DATA" /></description>
  </item>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

... will produce the following output document ...

```
<items>
  <item>
    <title>Product 1 name</title>
    <description>product description</description>
  </item>
  <item>
    <title>Product two name</title>
    <description>product description</description>
  </item>
</items>
```

Comment: Thanks Sean. What do you find is the best way to process this? Do you any particular application?

Comment: It depends on what your platform is. Windows? Mac? Android? Also server-side? or browser-side?

Comment: OSX. I just want to get the XML however possible. "View Generated Source" in FireFox works ok but I was wondering if there is an easier way?

Comment: So I presume server-side. I don't know any-thing about OSX. I understand XSLPalette is an IDE only where you get to choose the engine. Choose the bundled Saxon 8.7+ for XSLT 2.0, or better still, install the latest version of Saxon.  Also, please accept my answer.